# What is the appropriate way persist extended classes?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider the diagram:

[image]

I've been working with JPA for a short time and, so far, I have never had the need to persist extended classes... As you can see by the example, `SNMPNode`, `IPNode`, etc are all extended classes from `Node` that is also extended from `GeoLocation`.

I understand that I can annotate the master classes with `@MappedSuperclass` and `IPNode` and `SNMPNode` will inherit their properties for persisting... But in this scenario I will end up with nearly identical tables and, to my understanding, instead of doing that I could just group all information in Node and work with a single table.

Is this the way persistence of extended classes on JPA work or my concepts are wrong?

Same thing as a resumed piece of code:

```
public class Node extends GeoLocation {
    private String name;
    private Group group;
    private Location location;
    private Type type;
    private Company company;
}

public class IPNode extends Node {
    private Long id;
    private String ipAddress;
}

public class SNMPNode extends Node {
    private Long id;
    private SNMPServer server;
}
```

***[[ EDITED AFTER ANSWER FROM THIS POINT ]]***

***For the sake of contributing, here's a sample of what I end up doing:***

INode:

```
public interface INode {
    public Long getId();
    public void setId(Long id);

    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);

    public String getIpAddress();
    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress);

    public String getCommunity();
    public void setCommunity(String community);
}
```

Node:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("N")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="NODE_TYPE",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=20)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Node extends GeoLocation implements INode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    (... Overrides from INode ...)
}
```

IPNode:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("I")
public class IPNode extends Node {
    private String ipAddress;

    public String getIpAddress() { return this.ipAddress;}
    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) { this.ipAddress = ipAddress; }

    (... Overrides from INode ...)
}
```

SNMPNode:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class SNMPNode extends Node {
    private String community;

    public String getCommunity() { return community;}
    public void setCommunity(String community) { this.community = community; }

    (... Overrides from INode ...)
}
```

NodeRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface NodeRepository extends JpaRepository<Node, Long> { }
```

So now I can do stuff like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/spring/application-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class NodeRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    NodeRepository repo;

    private INode node;

    @Before
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(false)
    public void setup() {
        node = new IPNode();
        node.setName("ipNode");
        node.setIpAddress("1.1.1.1");
        repo.save((IPNode)node);

        node = new SNMPNode();
        node.setName("snmpNode");
        node.setIpAddress("2.2.2.2");
        node.setCommunity("some text");
        repo.save((SNMPNode)node);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void Test() throws Exception {
        INode testNode = repo.findOne(1L);
        assertNotNull(testNode);
    }
}
```

Both Node types are saved on the same table and so their keys can't repeat... My REST URL can grab them by /nodes/1 or /nodes/2, which was my main goal after all...

Thanks :)

Comment: Simple check google ("jpa inheritance"): You'll get http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: Very nice docs. The example tables make it very easy to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your base class is annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` then inheritance is only relevant in the OOP context. The `@MappedSuperclass` properties are simply copied to each sub-class associated database table and you can only query for sub-class entities.

[Single table inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/cmp30cfg016.htm#CEGDJIFH) yields the best performance (no join or union is involved) at the price of not being able to declare not-nullable all specific sub-class properties (since all base and all sub-class specific properties go to a single database table).

With [joined inheritance tables](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/cmp30cfg016.htm#CEGBDAIJ) you can have the base class properties in a base database table, and each specific sub-class has it's own associated table. The sub-class table is linked with the base database table through a FK, so you need to join these tables to fetch a sub-class entity. As opossed to `@MappedSuperclass`, the base class is queryable since both the OOP context and the database reflect the inheritance model.

Comment: Your answer along with these docs http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance made it very easy for me to understand. Thanks.

My main concern was that this is going to be a REST application and Nodes will be retrieved with an URL like /nodes/<id>. But I wanted the same URL for IPNode or SNMPNode and having the IDs on those classes would not work because they could repeat... I guess I need an abstract Node class with the ID field in it and then decide between any of the table inheritances.

Comment: @MarcelusTrojahn, I'm trying to follow those examples, but unfortunately there are inconsitences betwen the link you provided and the ones in Vlad's reply. Look at the joined inheritance examples; annotation is different.